# Call to free causes the program to throw an exception

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, api, free

I was doing my homework when I stumbled upon the following problem. I should create a simple multi-threaded application using in C and using Windows API functions. Each thread would run a simple task, so i have decided to recycle some older stuff I did.

I have a header file:

http://pastebin.com/1aJFAwBg

And a source file:

http://pastebin.com/L127FGhG

Then in main, I make the following call:

```
LoadPoem();
ProcessPoem();
SavePoem();
```

LoadPoem opens up the file containing the original, allocates a buffer for input (variable loadedPoemBuffer) and stores the text from the file in it. ProcessPoem then allocates a buffer for the altered version (variable processedPoemBuffer) and fills it by repeatedly calling strtok. Then it frees loadedPoemBuffer and ends.
So far so good.
The problem emerges when I call SavePoem(), it correctly saves the data, but when it ends, it calls free(processedPoemBuffer) and throws an exception - corrupted heap. I can't seem to understand why. It seems to me that it does exactly the same operation as ProcessPoem before it, yet that function does not fail.

Can somebody please explain it to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First: I'm sorry for the typos, English isn't my native language.
Second: I don't get what you mean. It's not the whole thing, just a piece of code for one of the threads to execute. If that is what you meant by your comment. If it is so - sorry for not specifying it the first time.

Comment: No not a problem with typos, it is just that threading is not considered simple, quite the opposite actually, it is known to increase complexity.

Comment: I know, but the assignment was for a threaded program. And It should run only 2 threads. But you are definitely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

processedPoemBuffer appears to be LPWSTR which means your data is Unicode. Then you call _tcscat_s which, if you are building for Unicode expects the number of characters, not bytes. You need to divide your input file size by the size of a WCHAR for the _tcscat_s buffer length argument.

Comment: In ProcessPoem you could do something like: DWORD outputMax = (inputFileSize + 2) / sizeof(*processedPoemBuffer); Then use outputMax in your _tcscat_s calls. You may also want to use wcscat_s since you know your data is wide characters

Comment: Yup.  I looked briefly at this earlier and immediately suspected a buffer size issue, but didn't bother looking further.  You did, so +1

Answer (score -1):

Exception in `free` means that you call it with something that is not a result of a `malloc`. Init your `processedPoemBuffer` with NULL and check it at `free` :

```
void* processedPoemBuffer = NULL;
...
if (some_err) goto error;
... 
error:
if (processedPoemBuffer) // only delete checks for NULL
    free(processedPoemBuffer);
```

Comment: -1 : If a null pointer is passed as argument to free, no action occurs.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. It is definitely allocated with malloc and then freed. And only once. Maybe it will be better to pass the arrays as in/out parameters and do the actual allocation in main.